# How to initialize a static property before initializing a static class?

Tags: c#, static

Below `Class2` has a property that needs to be set before `GetSomething` is called, however because I access `Class2` at the top of `Class1` the property is always null when it gets to `Something` class.  I can't seem to figure out how to change my code to set the property before it's used.  Anyone?

**EDIT**
I want to pass the dependency from form1's constructor, not hardcode it further up the chain.

```
public partial class form1
{
    private static readonly ISomeConstructedClass someConstructedClass = Class1.SomeConstructedClass;
    public form1()
    {
        someConstructedClass.SomeDependency = new SomeDependency();
        someConstructedClass.Whatever();
    }
}
public static class Class1
{
    public static readonly ISomething something = (ISomething)Class2.GetSomething("something");
    public static ISomeConstructedClass SomeConstructedClass
    {
     get
     {
       return something.SomeConstructedClass;
     }
    }
```

}
        ....
    }

```
public class Class2
{   
    public static ISomeDependency SomeDependency
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
    public static GetSomething(string something)
    {
         switch(something)
         {
            case "something":
               return new Something( SomeDependency );
         }         
    }
}

  public class Something : ISomething
  {
      public ISomeDependency SomeDependency
      {
           get;
           set;
      }
      public Something(ISomeDependency someDependency)
      {
           SomeDependency = someDependency;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the property?

Comment: @SLaks - I added more code that hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Why are you initializing `someConstructedClass` with SomeDependency from Class2 if you are just going to set it in `form1`s contructor anyway? What do you want it set to before you set it to a `new SomeDependency()`?

Comment: @Cemafor - It's not? form1 is the entry point to the application that is where the dependency is created and then the idea is to pass it up to all other classes that need it.  That way I am able to pass in a fake to all the other classes.

Comment: is there some object that implements ISomeDependancy?

Comment: @terrybozzio - yes SomeDependency implements ISomeDependency

Comment: @O.O: I was confused about what you were trying to do before. I thought you wanted to initialize SomeDependency before form1 constructor was called.  I edited my answer and hopfuly I now understand what you are _really_ trying to do.

Comment: and is your getsomething method really like that?no return value?would not even compile if so...

Comment: and your class Something does not implement ISomething(you make a cast to ISomething in class1).

Comment: @terrybozzio - uh ya this is not code that will run :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Re]Edit:

I was confused about what you were trying to do before, you just need to create the dependency first.

```
public partial class form1
{
    private static /*readonly*/ ISomeConstructedClass someConstructedClass;
    public form1()
    {
        Class2.SomeDependency = new SomeDependency();
        someConstructedClass = Class1.SomeConstructedClass;
        someConstructedClass.Whatever();
    }
}
```

I would also move the creation of something into the property just to make sure it is not initialized too soon (before the form1 constructor is called).

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static ISomething something;
    public static ISomeConstructedClass SomeConstructedClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (something == null) {
                something = (ISomething)Class2.GetSomething("something");
            }
            return something.SomeConstructedClass;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can use a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  This is called before any static (or instance for that matter) fields or methods are called/accessed.

Something like:

```
static Class2() {
    SomeDependency = SomeDependencyYouNeed;
}
```

Comment: This looks fine if the ISomeDependency is hard coded in the constructor, since static constructors are parameterless.

Comment: @Taylor: Yeah, I'm not sure where he is actually wanting to get the dependency from so I figured I would offer something that may be able to help.

Comment: @Cemafor - you cannot assign static readonly fields in a non-static constructor, so what you have above will not work :(

Comment: @O.O Good catch, I overlooked the static modifier... But something will have to give.  If you don't know the dependency until an instance of form1 is being created, you may have to demote someConstructedClass to not be readonly.

Comment: @O.O: I guess alternativly you could setup some sort of event that pushes out the dependencies when it is set in Class2, but I think it would be best to just do some reworking and not have as many (or any) static methods/parameters.

Comment: @Cemafor - Nice. I knew I was over thinking something.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using static methods? It looks like you're attempting a sort of Dependency Injection. Either create an instance of Class2 and pass the dependency in the constructor (and don't use static methods), or pass the dependency as a parameter of the GetSomething() method.

```
public static GetSomething(string something, ISomeDependency dependency).
```

Comment: not all Somethings require this dependency, so it would not make sense to pass it in to GetSomething